# Adding XMP copyright Notice tag in DOCINFO PS to PDF

Tags: pdf, postscript, xmp

I am done with these tags.These are converted into XMP of pdf correctly except copyright tag

```
/Author string
/CreationDate string
/Creator string
/Producer string
/Title string
/Subject string
/Keywords string
/ModDate string
/DOCINFO pdfmark
```

But my problem is how to add copyright tag in it. I tried **"rights"** and **"Copyright"** like this in PS.

```
/rights (Kings Man)
and 
/copyright (Kings Man)
```

All other tag are showing Good in XMP Meta Data when Postscript Convert to PDF by Adobe Distiller But i am failing to introduce the copyright tag in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOCINFO pdfmark doesn't support either a Copyright or rights key, so you can't add either to the document information using it (only certain keys are permitted).

Ordinarily, at least, XMP metadata doesn't contain a copyright notice either. Now you can add keys to the PDF info dictionary and clearly you can add to the XML, but these would then be non-standard. I am not surprised that the pdfmark operator doesn't support adding non-standard keys.

Essentially, you can't do that, or at least not by using pdfmark.